# How to get the workflow authentication to work in Aviarc

Tags: authentication, aviarc

We are trying to roll out authentication into my app and it’s not working for us.

We have set up the Current Authority and Current Authorizer and have even set the login query to be just select ‘a’ so we are guaranteed to get a result set.

We have copied the Login workflow to workflows/system directory.

It doesn’t look like it’s even trying to run the login query.

**start.xml** workflow:

```
<workflow>
    <authenticate error-screen="login-error" dataset="login">
        <show-screen name="login" />
    </authenticate>
    <call-workflow name="home"/>
</workflow>
```

**login.xml** screen:

```
<screen xmlns:action="urn:aviarc:widget:com.aviarc.toronto.widget.core.action:1"
    xmlns:app="urn:aviarc:widget:application">

    <group-box visible="y" left="10" right="4" top="10" bottom="4" class="blue">

        <image height="80" width="245" left="10" top="5" class="mfcologo" />
        <line height="5" left="0" right="0" top="120" class="myerblue" />

        <text-static visible="y" left="74" top="151" width="80" height="20" text="User name:" />
        <text-static visible="y" left="234" top="151" width="80" height="20" text="Password:" />

        <text-edit name="username" left="74" top="182" width="100" height="20" field="login.user_name" />
        <text-edit name="password" left="234" top="182" width="100" height="20" field="login.user_password" datatype="password" />

        <button left="376" top="182" width="60" height="20" label="Login" action="Next"/>
    </group-box>
</screen>
```

**system/Login.xml** workflow:

```
<workflow xmlns:au-security="urn:aviarc:xmlcommand:au.com.aviarc.xmlcommand.security">

    <au-security:hash-text text="{$login.user_password}" result-field="login.hashed-password" />

    <dataset name="cslogin" databroker="loginqry" query="get-all">
        <param name="username" value="{$login.user_name}" />
        <param name="password" value="{$login.hashed-password}" />
    </dataset>

    <if test="dataset-empty" value1="cslogin">
        <then>
            <set-field field="login.authenticated" value="n"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <set-field field="login.authenticated" value="y"/>
        </else>
    </if>
</workflow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Workflow authentication requires "username" field to be populated prior to entering it, otherwise the authentication would fail immediately and login error screen will be displayed.

In your example it is fairly easy to fix, changing the line in **login.xml** screen from:

```
<text-edit name="username" left="74" top="182" width="100" height="20" field="login.user_name" />
```

to be:

```
<text-edit name="username" left="74" top="182" width="100" height="20" field="login.username" />
```

and updating reference to it in the **system/Login** workflow.